# Hadoop - composite key

Tags: hadoop, composite-key

Suppose I have a tab delimited file containing user activity data formatted like this:

```
timestamp  user_id  page_id  action_id
```

I want to write a hadoop job to count user actions on each page, so the output file should look like this:

```
user_id  page_id  number_of_actions
```

I need something like composite key here - it would contain user_id and page_id. Is there any generic way to do this with hadoop? I couldn't find anything helpful. So far I'm emitting key like this in mapper:

```
context.write(new Text(user_id + "\t" + page_id), one);
```

It works, but I feel that it's not the best solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just compose your own `Writable`. In your example a solution could look like this:

```
public class UserPageWritable implements WritableComparable<UserPageWritable> {

  private String userId;
  private String pageId;

  @Override
  public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
    userId = in.readUTF();
    pageId = in.readUTF();
  }

  @Override
  public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
    out.writeUTF(userId);
    out.writeUTF(pageId);
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(UserPageWritable o) {
    return ComparisonChain.start().compare(userId, o.userId)
        .compare(pageId, o.pageId).result();
  }

}
```

Although I think your IDs could be a `long`, here you have the `String` version. Basically just the normal serialization over the `Writable` interface, note that it needs the default constructor so you should always provide one.

The `compareTo` logic tells obviously how to sort the dataset and also tells the reducer what elements are equal so they can be grouped.

`ComparisionChain` is a nice util of [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).

**Don't forget to override equals and hashcode!** The partitioner will determine the reducer by the hashcode of the key.

Comment: ComparisionChain really makes easy for this use case. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own class that implements Writable and WritableComparable that would compare your two fields.

Pierre-Luc Bertrand