# I need to modify the regular wordcount program in map reduce by giving a directory as input

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Instead of giving a single file as input , i wanted to give a directory which can contain any no files in it. I wanted the output to be written in a way

Input :

File 1 File 2 File3

Output :

File 1 File 2 File3

while each file should have its word count in the corresponding file. To identify which file is used in the map i can use context.getInputSplit() . But how can i make it to write output in  the way i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the input splits from your mapper to identify the files they came from, and use that combined with [MultipleOutputs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.0.3-alpha/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html) to write out to separate files from your reducer.

However, you will need to pass the file it came from to the reducer, so you may need to make a composite key object and write a custom `Partitioner` and `WritableComparator` to carry across the both the filename and original key together. See: [Hadoop - composite key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427090/hadoop-composite-key)